# Adding a CA Cert to Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I believe this is more user related but wanted to ask here.
I need to update the CA cert on our Salesforce instance.
However, when I go to download the cert at the CA it doesn't list Salesforce as a type pf server. Which type of server cert will work with Salesforce?

Comment: Erm... normal? Generic? Probably cer file with 3 levels of authority will work well. What options do you have? Did you generate the cert signing request in SF and are just uploading it signed back? Or are you hoping to upload it from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you select "other" when you go into GoDaddy as far as the server selection is concerned.
Thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).